# limiting returned jquery selection when more than one meets criteria

Tags: jquery

How can I limit the result in jquery to only one word? I am selecting from a large table, and then taking specific text from the cells and putting them at the top for a quick reference:

```js
var admitting = $(".top_IM_prov_am").text($(".IM_day_provider").text());
if (admitting.text() === "See Hospitalist Above") {
  $(".top_IM_prov_am").text($(".hospitalist_provider").text());
}

locate("Internal Medicine ETC Admissions Day", "IM_day"); // Output: .IM_day_provider | .IM_day_provider_contact | .IM_provider_contact_cell
locate("Admitting-Transfers-Consults- Day", "hospitalist");

function locate(specialty, newName) {
  $("tr>td:contains(" + specialty + ")").not(':first').addClass("'" + newName + "'")
    .next().next().addClass(" " + newName + "_provider")
    .next().next().next().next().addClass(" " + newName + "_provider_contact")
    .next().addClass(" " + newName + "_provider_contact_cell");
```

The result returns two rows with the same value in the td. I want to limit this to one. I was considering using the :first selector but I am not having much luck. You will also see that I added a `".not(:first)`, but this is to limit my `.addClass`. I also tried to do something like this:

```
$("tr>td:first:contains("+specialty+")").not(':first').addClass("'"+newName+"'")
```

but adding the `:first` selector to the `:contains` selector doesn't work.

The other alternative I would consider is splitting the two selected rows into two separate classes, however I feel like that may be more complicated.

Comment: Instead of :first selector use the .first() function on the returned collection

Comment: @user3154108 why? They do the exact same thing

Comment: :first is deprecated and also not as intuitive to use. For example the way you use :first right now, you take the first TD and look if it contains... if it does not contain then your collection is empty. :first would need to come after contains, but really, better use .first()

Comment: makes sense. but my next question would be how would I use .first() in this scenario? $("tr>td:contains("+specialty+")").first("td").addClass("'"+newName+"'").not(':first').--am I using this correctly? I'm not sure how to use :not without the depreciated :first

Comment: @Jrapa86 I am not sure what your .not is supposed to do. `$("tr>td:contains("+specialty+")").first("td")` will return the first td which contains your string and is a direct child of a tr.

Comment: I'm trying to add assign a class to that table cell as well. When I do that though, it for some reason adds the class to a td higher up on the hierarchy, (the first td) so I assigned a :not in order to prevent that.

Comment: Sounds like you are nestling tds? Maybe it is best to provide some HTML to give context